# Get all variations of certain numbers certain length and certain min&max values?

Tags: php, algorithm, combinatorics

Funny, but I'm really stucked with this probably simple task.

What I need is very simple

```
11111
11112
11121
11211
```

and so on.

This is what I've done so far (but it doesn't work correclty of course)

```
 $patterns=array_fill(0,5,'1'); //'1' is a minimal digit (but it can be higher)
 $cnt=0;
 $maxV=3; //max digit (can be any)
 $inc='Y';
 while($cnt++<100){
 for ($i = count($patterns)-1; $i>0; $i--){
 If($patterns[$i]<$maxV && $inc){$patterns[$i]++; $inc='';}
 If($patterns[$i]==$maxV){$patterns[$i]=1; $inc='Y';}
 }
 echo implode($patterns),'<br>';
 If($i==0){$inc='Y';}

 }



 the result is 

 112
 121
 122
 111
 112
 121
 122
 111
 112
 121
 122
 111
```

is not quite as what I need

Important that I need to set length and min and max values for resulting numbers.

Any advices?

Comment: Does it have to be 1s and 2s? - this looks remarkably like a binary switch otherwise (0s and 1s) and it would probably be easier to deal with... depending on exactly what you're trying to do of course.

Comment: @CD001 no, it can has any min and max values

Comment: Please add more examples of input and expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your last sample may work. Except for the first result `1111111`. It is doing too much work. You are looping over the entire array for each increment. Also `array_sum` is going to loop over the array as well.

A simpler example using recursion which works:

```
function printPattern($len, $min, $max){
    printPatternRec($len, $min, $max, array(), 0);
}
function printPatternRec($len, $min, $max, $pattern, $cur){
    if($cur==$len){
        echo implode($pattern),'<br>';
        return;
    }
    for($val=$min;$val<$max;$val++){
        $pattern[$cur]=$val;
        printPatternRec($len, $min, $max, $pattern, $cur+1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can implement an odometer that increments the last digit. When the digit wraps, the next digit is incremented until you reach the initial state, that is until the number to wrap isn't out of bounds for your pattern size:

```
function echo_combo($size, $base)
{
    $pattern = array_fill(0, $size, 0);
    $ix = 0;

    while ($ix < $size) {
        $i = $size;

        while ($i--) {
            echo $pattern[$i] + 1;
        }
        echo "<br />";

        $pattern[$ix]++;
        while ($pattern[$ix] == $base) {
            $pattern[$ix] = 0;
            $ix++;
            if ($ix == $size) return;
            $pattern[$ix]++;
        }
        $ix = 0;
    }
}

echo_combo(5, 2);
```

(I'm not a PHP person, so the code probably doesn't look very php-ish. Sorry for that.)

Answer (score 0):

I can be wrong but I see it looks like it works ))

```
$patternlen=8;
$maxV=3;
$patternsMap=array_fill(0,$patternlen,'1');
$cnt=0;
$inc='Y';
while($cnt++<100000){
$inc='Y';
for($i = count($patternsMap)-1; $i>=0; $i--){
If($inc){
$patternsMap[$i]++; $inc='';
If($patternsMap[$i]==$maxV){$patternsMap[$i]=1; $inc='Y';}
}
}

echo $cnt,'. ',implode($patternsMap),' ',array_sum($patternsMap),'<BR>';

If($patternlen*$maxV-$patternlen<=array_sum($patternsMap)){break;}

}
```